# Why are the number of rows greater than the number of columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm currently reading a book on the basics of Linear Algebra, and I'm stuck at a concept.

Suppose we had

$ Ax = b $

where A is $ m x n$ matrix and x is a $ nx1 $ vector. The book stated that in order for the equation to have solution such that $ b \in \mathbb{R}^m $, number of rows has to be greater than or equal to the number of columns, that is $ n \geq m $ . I can't seem to undestand why.

Can someone please explain it to me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $b\in \mathbb R^m$, then the number of rows is $m$ and consequently the number of columns is $n$. It´s a contradiction to "number of rows has to be greater than or equal to the number of columns, that is $ n\geq m$""

Comment: Did the book's original text include the word "unique"?  If so, it's probably critical.

Comment: It's basically not true as you wrote it, you must have missed some important detail.